# If a finitely complete category has system of factorization (E,M) then the class M is stable under pullbacks.

Tags: category-theory

We have to show that  in this diagram ( see below) if $f \in$$\mathcal M$ then $g \in$$\mathcal M$.

[image: Pullback]

So $\forall e \in$ $\mathcal E$ we have to show $e \perp g$. I consider this diagram:

[image: Pullback]

But since $f \in \mathcal M$ we know $\exists !$ $ \beta_1 :$ $B^{'}$$ \rightarrow C$ making the outer triangle commute. In addition we can also get a pullback factorization $ \beta_2$ because of $ \beta_1$.

It is clear that $ k \circ \alpha_1 = k \circ \beta_2 \circ e$ but what I need is $ \beta_2 \circ e = \alpha_1$

How can I finish this last step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the proof in [Abstract and Concrete Categories/The Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf) Proposition 14.15 on Page 247.

The idea is that you factorize $g$ into $g_e$ and $g_m$ through some intermediate object $F$, $g_e: A\to F, g_m: F\to B$ . Then you can use $g_e\perp f$ to get some $d: F\to C$. With that you can apply the pullback property to $d$ and $g_e$ to get some $g_e': F\to A$, which turns out to be a right inverse for $g_e$ and with that, it follows that $g\in M$.